# TypeError: popper is null

Tags: bootstrap-4, popper.js

My problem: when i click on the dropdown, i have an error message in my console:

[image]

An extract of my twig:

```
<select class="tabledit-input form-control dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" name="color" >
    {% for item in items %}
        <option value="{{ item.id }}" selected="">{{ item.Label }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success validbtn">Valid</button>
```

I check in my package.json and in the app.js and everything is ok. I have read that it could be link to the data-toggle="dropdown".But i don't know where is the error.

I don't know if it's important but this select is in a cell of a datatable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't use `dropdown` classes with `select` tag because of both `select` and `dropdown` is used for different reasons.

`select` tag is usually used for posting some data to the backend and `dropdown` is usually used for redirection.

If you are using the dropdown, don't forget to add `popper.js`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when the button with `data-toggle="dropdown"` wasn't a direct child of the `<div class="dropdown">` element.

The solution was to move it one level up, ie:

❌ Doesn't work:

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <span>
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</button>
  </span>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <!-- items -->
  </div>
</div>
```

✔ Works:

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <!-- items -->
  </div>
</div>
```